# Bind Window to Another Window and always on Top

Tags: winapi

I need to create a Small Window that is bound to the Big Window.

Big window is a window of another process.

When Big window moves the Small window moves too.

When Big window comes to top then Small window comes too.

Small window should be always on top relatively to Big window.

What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to inject a DLL into that process, subclass and handle the `WM_MOVING` windows message. It can stay on top using a normal `SetWindowPos()` call.